# When will Ruby's if condition be executed?

Tags: ruby

In my latest task, I found some code like this:

```
if false
  print "a"
elsif true  
  print "b"
else  
   print "c"
end
```

Is if else statement correct? Will if ever be executed?

Comment: Is what correct? The syntax? What do you mean by "When Ruby's if condition will run?"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Your question is not clear? What are you asking?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by correct. This code will print b, as the `if false` branch will not execute and then the `elsif true` branch will.

Comment: Ternary booleans... Only in another universe.

Comment: @Renan http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: @neminem here's a 1-up to that, by yours truly: http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/p/18692/229458.aspx

Comment: @Renan I can beat that. My favorite "boolean", as documented in msdn, their wonderful 5-state "tristate" bool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msotristate%28v=office.11%29.aspx (granted, the descriptions of the 3 states other than true/false are "not supported", but it's still in the documentation.)

Comment: @neminem ok, I concede you the victory on that. I've been beaten by the world's second largest corporation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will always print "b".

One explanation is that this code was put in as a placeholder for some real logic which was supposed to be added at a later point in time.

Comment: Ugh. If I found that code in something we'd written in-house, there'd be some very pointed remarks about the proper use of comments and to NOT put nonsense code into place.